# SonarQube - Failed to create working path:

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube, bamboo

I have following problem with SonarQube analysis through Bamboo build.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.0.1:sonar (default-cli) on project grip: Unable to load component class org.sonar.core.platform.PluginLoader: 
Unable to load component class org.sonar.core.platform.PluginClassloaderFactory: Unable to load component interface org.sonar.api.utils.TempFolder: Failed to create working path: /home/users/jiradmin/.sonar -> [Help 1]
```

Bamboo plan just fire maven task: `sonar:sonar` .

Google suggest only to clear sonar temp folder and check bamboo agent permissions for directory create/save. (Currently I don't have possibility to check this).

Do you have any idea how to fix it? (or maybe I should write to official SonarQube support)

Bamboo uses maven 3.2.5 and jdk 1.8.0_45. Project is multi-module (uses reactor plugin).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must verify the user account trying to run the analysis has write permissions to the cited directory. Until that has been confirmed/corrected, no one can go any further with this.

Comment: Bamboo's task used JDK8 and maven-3.2.5 to fire sonar analysis, after changing mvn version to 3.3.9 errors gone :D